# Weird '?' characters all over inside vim editor in tmux session

Tags: vim, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I am excited to use WSL feature of Windows 10 and I choose Ubuntu distribution.

I installed vim version 8.0 and tmux version 2.6. However to my frustration, when I use vim inside tmux session, all I can see is '?' characters regardless of what key I press.

[image: vim showing '?']

Comment: Check the font that you are using. Also you didn't mention the distribution also not the terminal. How did you launch wsl?

Comment: Thanks @CarlosRafaelRamirez for the comment, I used Ubuntu Distro found through Microsoft store in windows 10. Then I change it to Ubuntu 18.04.LTS and now it works fine. So it seems distro issue

Comment: Hmm after a while the problem come back again.I did not recall what I did in between, just installing NERDTree vim plugin, but I dont think it is relevant. This is really frustrating :(

Comment: Install Xming on windows, on your terminal, set DISPLAY to :0.0 and run xterm.  Does the same thing happen on the xterm terminal?

Comment: Yes the same thing still happen